# How to set wave height of WaveView according to SeekBar's progress?

Tags: java, android

[image: GIF]

Above `GIF` is current look of my music player.

The center `layout` is [`WaveView`](https://github.com/gelitenight/WaveView) and front of that is a simple musical note `vector-drawable`.

I first tried to set `Waveview` progress according to `SeekBar`'s progress **without any song playing** to test it. And it worked perfectly fine (Seekbars current progress/100 which is `0.01` to `1.00`).

Now what I want to do is set `WaveView`'s **Water Level** (height of water) according to song progress.

When song will play, the water level will be set from `0.0f` to `1.0f` and revealing the White Music note icon.

**Note that** the `WaveView`'s water level can only be set from `0.0f` to `1.0f`.

I tried multiple ways but could not solve this problem.

Here is my code which **should return** 0.01, 0.02 and so on ... :

```
this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (mainMediaPlayer != null) {
            currentDurationPosition = mainMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()/1000;
            songSeekBar.setProgress(currentDurationPosition+1);
            topSongTitle.setText(songsList.get(currentSongPosition).getName());
            songCircleProgress.setWaterLevelRatio(currentDurationPosition/mainMediaPLayer.getDuration());
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No song is playing now", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
});
```

Comment: Im not sure I understood everything, if you succeded without the song, what difference is there when you add the song? Why does it not work with only progress/100 as you were doing before? With your current function, you will never have anything above 0.09f except when progress is >= 10000

Comment: @Macmist some how I get the value 0.0 all the time. That's why I've asked this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After rereading your code, I think I see two issues here:

first, your `staticFloat` initialisation:

```
private static float staticFloat = 1/100;
```

By doing this, you are actually doing an integer division, then converting it to a float. 1/100 in integer division equals to 0, so your float will always be 0.0f. 
To have the 0.01 value, you need to do

```
private static float staticFloat = 1/100f; // or 1f/100
```

This way you are dividing an int by a float, or the opposite, and it will have a floating result.

Secondly, your `getWaterPosition` function. You are returning 0 when progress is 0. In every other case, you are returning, well... 0 too.

Why? You are returning on each case

```
returnPosition = minusPosition - (minusPosition - staticFloat);
```

which is equivalent to:

```
returnPosition = minusPosition - minusPosition + staticFloat;
```

and again equivalent to:

```
returnPosition = staticFloat;
```

and as we've seen before, this would always be 0, or even 0.01f when you will fix it.

I guess you made some errors when coming with that formula. But won't it work by doing only something like `return progress / 100f;` ?

You can also add in your xml a max value to your seekbar, so it's never above 100 and you'll have your return between 0.0f and 1.0f

```
<SeekBar
    // initialisation
    android:max="100"/>
```

Comment: I guess my friend made a mess by uploading wrong code which is not mine. Sorry for that ! This is not the code I was stuck on.

But by using your suggestions I have successfully solved this.

Thanks a lot !

I am putting the original problem I got and accepting your answer !

Comment: I've put the original problem which I was facing. Don't know from where my friend got that crappy code.
Again, thanks for concern ! I've accepted answer, which helped me to solve the problem by putting f here : `songCircleProgress.setWaterLevelRatio((currentDurationPosition/1f)/(mainMediaPLayer.getDuration()/1f));`